# My Google AppEngine deployment failed. How can I revert?

Tags: git, deployment, gcloud

The command 
gcloud app deploy --project xxxx --version 1
failed with the following response:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Filename cannot contain '.', '..', '\r', start with '-', '*ah/', or '\n': git/t/t4013/diff.diff*--patch-with-raw_-r_initial..side
This happened after creating a CloudStore repository and pushing to it, the next deployment, which should have uploaded 1 or 2 files, instead uploaded over three thousand. I have since added .git (which is where the above referenced file came from) to .gitignore. Now when I deploy, only one file gets uploaded, but the deployment still chokes on the same file. Is there a way to delete all the uploaded files and try again? Bumping up the version number doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER MIND! The offending file was in git, not .git. Once I added /git to .gcloudignore, the app deployed without error.